# Show that a holomorphic function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq c|z|^n$ must be $f(z)=a\cdot z^n$ for some a.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such there exists a $c\in\mathbb C$ with $|f(z)|\leq c\cdot |z|^n$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Show that there exists an $a\in\mathbb C$ with $f(z)=a\cdot z^n$.

Proof.

My general idea is to show that the taylor series only has one non-zero coefficient:

$\displaystyle |a_k|\leq\frac{k!}{2\pi}\oint_{|w|=r}\frac{|f(w)|}{|w|^{k+1}}dw\leq \frac{k!}{2\pi}\oint_{|w|=r}\frac{c\cdot|w|^n}{|w|^{k+1}}dw\leq
\\\displaystyle\leq \frac{c\cdot k!}{2\pi}\oint_{|w|=r}|w|^{n-k-1}dw$

Now using the standard estimate since $\oint=2\pi r$:

$\displaystyle \leq c\cdot k!\cdot r^{n-k}\longrightarrow\begin{cases}0,\ k>n\\c\cdot n!,\ k=n\\ \infty,\ k<n\end{cases}$ as $r\to\infty$

In conlusion the taylor series for now looks like $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k z^k+ a_n z^n$ with $|a_n|\leq n!\cdot c$. What do I do with the remaining summands?

Edit: I would say that for $k<n$ we have $|z|^k>|z|^n$ for $z\in D_1(0)$. So since the estimate has to hold for all $z\in \mathbb C$ we can't have that either.

Comment: Consider the behavior of $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ near zero.

Comment: For $k<n$ use the limit $r\to 0$ in the coefficient bound to get $a_k=0$.

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way to prove this is using the fact that every bounded entire function is constant and applying it to $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$
$$$$
To show that $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ is defined and is holomorphic at $0$, we use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities. The hypothesis of the theorem is satisfied.

Comment: Oh my god... You're obviously right, it's just Liouville's theorem. Shame on me.

Comment: You still need to argue that $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ is entire, that is, is defined and holomorphic at $z=0$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I edited the answer.